# How to use Template Literal Types as a return type property in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I am trying out the new [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) feature from the [TypeScript 4.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#template-literal-types) release and would like to create function accepting a *string literal* argument which is then used to declare the properties of the return type object.

As an experiment I'm trying to create a little wrapper around React's [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) function, but can't get it to work.

This is what I've tried:

```
function useNamedState<TValue>(name: string, initialValue: TValue): {
    [typeof name]: TValue;
    [`set${Capitalize<typeof name>}`]: (newValue: TValue) => void;
} {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

    return {
        [name]: value,
        [`set${capitalize(name)}`]: newValue => setValue(newValue),
    };
}
```

I'm not sure what the right syntax should be here. I would like to achieve the following API:

```
const {apples, setApples} = useNamedState<number|null>('apples', null);
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an extra type to capture the actual string literal type for the `name` parameter. Also you need to use mapped types, or the predefined `Record` mapped type to create a type with keys from a string literal type.

The one complication is the TS does not support partial argument inference, so you have a few options as to how you define the function.

1. Single function with either explicit type arguments, or inferred ones but with type assertions:

```
function useNamedState<TValue, TName extends string>(name: TName, initialValue: TValue): Record<TName, TValue> & Record<`set${Capitalize<typeof name>}`, (newValue: TValue) => void>
{ /*...*/ }

const {apples, setApples} = useNamedState<number|null, 'apples'>('apples', null); // explicit args 
const {bannana, setBannana} = useNamedState('bannana', null as null | number); // implicit args,but with type assertion on value
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+ccAZlBCHAORTo4DGM1AUACboMA2OdZyAOybAIAuAxxhguLsABe6ABQA3HF2ToAXHFQwowAQHMAlNt36jAbhYtSg4aJQYAcjhDo22POgA8AFQA1NQ0AGjg-V3c4dAAPfAE2VB09A0MAPkUBNy1wyPQwg2lgNSD1HMDg9FM4ACVOaDZ-PLCKsrS4ADJa+qhGgAMMGAASBABhSWk1eV8YAE8wdAhSOCz3NMI+sMz0AHdSjW1WjWM4AF525QhgNjSWBBYSEgZRXTgAbVUysMH99ABdM5OLC4fCKQowYpcX7GawPR50GDIKBie6PNHvVb-bSfUJw9HvAboYYICRSGTTTLZYwbP7abZ7SqHaFndo-Sr06EhPFEOA4JJ1Z69JrZFq-dpdAUNHyE4njMlTBQ+OYLJYrbLrTZwDmM8LM85wS7XNLWQg2Z4CV4ISRgLjoVDfIkAQTANrtxFOQLynhBvgEyBAACN0FAAD5+rhcMLUa221DUDLRl2x6hhcNcGFwAD0meiMRtwAY0l5UEMSRY5stAZwAiyWQdMAAQtXazh3Z7st7vIpqFWa9WcCmVsgI7ykmm4CGh4Hgxns3BQPnC-BeKWQgHkPAdtIABZwZUEPkYWAiMSOHEEIA)

2. With function currying. With parameters in same order (but clunky type argument list)

```
function useNamedState <TName extends string>(name: TName)
{
    return function  <TValue>(initialValue: TValue): Record<TName, TValue> & Record<`set${Capitalize<typeof name>}`, (newValue: TValue) => void> {
        // ....
    }
}
// TValue specified in the middle is hard to read
const {apples, setApples} = useNamedState('apples')<number|null>(null);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

3. With function currying. With parameters in reverse order (but ok type argument list)

```
function useNamedState <TValue>(initialValue: TValue)
{
    return function <TName extends string>(name: TName): Record<TName, TValue> & Record<`set${Capitalize<typeof name>}`, (newValue: TValue) => void> {
         //....
    }
}

const {apples, setApples} = useNamedState<number|null>(null)('apples');
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDKMCGN1wC+ccAZlBCHAORTo4DGM1AUACboMA2OdZyAOybAIAuAxxhguLsABe6ABQA3HF2ToAXHFQwowAQHMAlNt36jAbhalBw0SgwA5HCHRtseAgB4AKgDU1DQA+RQNpYDVA9S04AKD0YxYEFhISOhhkKDFbIRgRMT8XNzh0AA98ATZUHT0DQ1CBV1jfYsTtACVOaDYi5oAaOOiQuAAyOC6GHu8AAwwYABIEAGFJaTV5dG8YAE8wdAhSOCa3YMIZwcUBdAB3YZb74zgAXmC4ZQhgNjeUtL-xUS6OAAbVUMUG83uAF0Xo4sLh8GEBBEogljNZUv90uhMtlEJisX9gSd0FDtGCNP0CYSSMC5jilhIpDJNldmsZzmS4FdbvdtPEYk9XjocfceXc0VSacQcDVJtNWgMhgk3uN5VBevTFis1iyFNs9gcjiSzhdudcJTF+Y8Xm8Pl9gtY-oQWC6WFMBECEJIwFx0KgITiAIJgX3+4jPOFtDwIrYCZAgABG6CgAB941wuI1kJnjIpqD6-ahqOigA)

Comment: It's unfortunate that partial type argument inference isn't supported, hopefully it will be added in the future. Thanks for your complete answer.